# MySQL Group By & Count... Can I do a nested grouping?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table called `activity` that uses the following columns:

```
LoginDate, LoginID, Department, IsMGR
```

I tried this query:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*), 
         DATE_FORMAT( LoginDate, '%m%d%Y' ) AS LogDate, 
         LoginID, Department
    FROM `activity` 
   WHERE IsMGR = '1' 
     AND LoginDate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY LoginID, LogDate 
ORDER BY LoginID,LogDate DESC
```

What I end up with is:

```
3   02172011    sdavis  accounting
1   02162011    sdavis  accounting
2   02132011    sdavis  accounting
1   02102011    sdavis  accounting
5   02092011    sdavis  accounting
4   02082011    sdavis  accounting
1   03182011    dmorris     marketing
1   03092011    dmorris     marketing
6   04142011    cchan   technology
1   03282011    cchan   technology
2   03262011    cchan   technology
2   03112011    cchan   technology
1   03102011    cchan   technology
```

Which is giving a count of how many times on each of those days that they logged in. What I'd want is a only one count per day and having all of the days grouped for each person with a count of how many days they logged in, along with the last day. Using the data sample above, the output I desire should be

```
6 02172011 sdavis accounting
2 03182011 dmorris marketing
5 04142011 cchan technology
```

So what I'd want is to somehow group the above grouped results by a 2nd set of criteria...?

Comment: Why do you `GROUP BY LoginID, LogDate` if you need a result that doesn't take care of `LogDate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct LoginDate) AS NumLogins,
       DATE_FORMAT( MAX(LoginDate), '%m%d%Y' ) AS LastLogDate, 
       LoginID, Department
FROM activity 
WHERE IsMGR='1' AND LoginDate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY LoginID, Department
ORDER BY LoginID, Department DESC
```

Comment: Thanks to you, and the person below as well! I only needed to adjust one bit of your suggested query: SELECT COUNT(distinct DATE_FORMAT(LoginDate,'%m%d%y')... and the grouping worked as I'd hoped!

Thanks again! -CDF

Comment: @Bohem `GROUP BY LoginID, Department`

Comment: @CDF: The adjustment you say you needed indicates that `Logindate` is a `datetime` and not `date` type. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    count(distinct LoginDate) as loginCount,
    max(LoginDate) as lastLoginDate,
    LoginID,
    Department
FROM `activity` 
where IsMGR='1' 
and LoginDate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY LoginID, Department 
ORDER BY LoginID, lastLoginDate DESC
```